# Angular + Spring, $http and $location to get the project name

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

Im developing a mobile internet booking engine using spring mvc (backend) and angular in the front end.

Usually my path would go like this http://localhost:8080/mobileibenew/booking;

From within the controller, I make $http calls to the backend (spring) to get or post api data. For example:

```
$http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/mobileibenew/availability',
            data : {"routes": routeData, "adults": adults, "searchBy": "BY_FLIGHT"});
```

**mobileibenew** is the name of the spring project. If I change the name of the project, then this would directly affect my front end code i.e. the $http calls.

What would be the best way to retrieve the name of my spring project in the front end (without string manipulation)?

It would have to look like this:

```
$http({ method : 'POST', url: projectname + '/booking', data : 'somedata'});
```

Where "projectname" could be a variable that holds the name of the project.

This eliminates me from having to go into each file and having to change the name.

Please keep in mind this is a spring project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to code your context in URL (in your case mobileibenew). When a server returns  scripts to browser, browser is aware of from which context server has returned the request.

Use relative URLs in javascript like below. So when you change the project name or deploy using different context name, you don't have to change anything

```
$http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : 'availability',
            data : {"routes": routeData, "adults": adults, "searchBy": "BY_FLIGHT"});
```

Comment: Thank you my friend. I will keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Define a [contant](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant) in your app module like

```
angular.module('app',[]).constant('PROJECT_NAME','projectname');
```

Then you can inject it everywhere like

```
.controller('MyController', function ($http, PROJECT_NAME) {
  $http({ method : 'POST', url: PROJECT_NAME + '/booking', data :  'somedata'});
});
```

Comment: I've thought about using constants, but I might have had to do some string manipulation to extract the project name hence I didn't use it. However I could use this in a different context, so thank you for taking the time :).